# Convert Require to Import

Tags: javascript, import, discord.js, require, chalk

I am currently working on a Discord.js Bot in [replit](https://repl.it). The example code I found, which I used to get started with the bot, begins with this line of code.
`const { Client, Intents, Message } = require('discord.js'); const client = new Client( { intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] } );`
I am trying to style the console/terminal output with [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk). However, Chalk requires ESM. To fix this, I go into package.json and add `"type":"module"`. At this point, the **chalk** works, but *not* **discord.js**, because it uses `require()`. How would I change the require into an `import` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using package named bable, as it will compile your code down into supported one. you can read about it here https://github.com/babel/babel

Comment: I honestly don't know how, but I somehow did this post twice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205284/chalk-issues-in-nodejs/72205737#72205737